Figuring out the apparent constellation an object (planet B) is from an observer (planet A)
https://imgur.com/a/tMakd6R
The first image is a visual of my problem as well as another short explanation of my goal. I could just use software such as stellarium or skyfield, but I would like to be able to make approximate calculations for my own custom solar system.
Both planets in the example have perfectly circular, non-inclined orbits (so e=0 and i=0). SMA is short for semimajor axis (a). Period (P) is years, and M.A. stands for Mean Anomaly (M).
This problem has been driving me crazy for a few days now and my stubborn nature will not allow me to rest until it has been conquered. I don't even know if I'm on the right track. If there's something I'm missing entirely or should be doing differently, please let me know!
Visual example
Google sheets calculated

@JeanMarie edited post! Sorry for that. New to stack exchange.

Welcome to stackexchange. That said, to get help here you have to show us the mathematics and what you have tried so far. Just two images of your handwritten work and a link to a spreadsheet are not enough. Use mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

In order to clarify the question : do you want for example to take the "point of view" of a Martian looking for the position of Venus in "his sky" ?
